# Javascript function return

Tags: javascript, return, hebrew

I need to check if the name field is only Hebrew letters[א-ת],
now the function work good, but if I enter letters from two different languages like "abcdאבג" it ignores and return true and I need it to return false,
thank you

```
function justHeb(str){
    ok = true;
        for (var i=0;i<str.length&&ok;i++)
        {
            if (!str[i].match(/[א-ת]/))
            {
                ok=false;
                return false;
            }
            else return true;
        }
}

function firstName(str){
    if(justHeb(document.getElementById("firstname").value)){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

function checkAll(){
    if(firstName()){
        alert("true");
    }
    else 
        alert("false");
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking every letter and NOT just one regular expression check?

Comment: this is what my teacher wants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `return true;` to *outside* the `for` loop.  Otherwise your code will accept any string that simply *starts* with a Hebrew character.

```
function justHeb(str){
    var ok = true;
        for (var i=0;i<str.length&&ok;i++)
        {
            if (!str[i].match(/[א-ת]/))
            {
                ok=false;
                return false;
            }
        }
    return true;
}
```

Now, you could simplify even further by letting the regular expression engine do that work for you:

```
function justHeb(str) {
  return /^[א-ת]*$/.test(str);
}
```

The leading `^` means that the match must start at the beginning of the string. The `*` says to accept a sequence of zero or more characters in that range, and finally the `$` says that the match must end at the end of the string.

Comment: thank you,but i mean i need if the string contain other char it's return false and not any situation return true

Comment: @MaorBenezri yes, I understand that. You want the return value to be `true` only when the string contains only characters in that range, right?  So, `abcת` should return `false`, right?

Comment: @MaorBenezri OK, well maybe you can try my suggestions and see if that helps.